# Space error using powershell, cmd command for postgresql with arguments

Tags: postgresql, powershell, cmd

```
$output = cmd /c ""C:\Program Files '(x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe" -t -d testdb1 -U myname -c "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'testdb2'""
```

returns an error:

```
> 'testdb <<<< '"" is missing the terminator: '.
```

How do I fix this error? I am already using `""` to wrap the whole argument for cmd and using single quote ' to escape the open bracket (

Comment: you have a single quote in `C:\Program Files '(x86)`, is this intentional?

Comment: that is the escape character in powershell. see [link](http://ss64.com/ps/syntax-esc.html)

Comment: The single quote is not an escape character in PowerShell. Note that the link you quote says it's the grave accent \`. The whole thing with `cmd` should be unnecessary here anyway. Nesting commands will only *worsen* your quoting problems, not make them better.

Answer (score 1):

The quoting is totally off in your attempt and should be unnecessary (unless Postgres actually looks for `cmd` as it's parent process, which I'd find highly unlikely). Do note that PowerShell *is* a shell, so running external commands isn't unusual or difficult. Wrapping them in `cmd /c`, or `Invoke-Expression` or both should nearly never be necessary.

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe' -t -d testdb1 -U myname -c "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'testdb2'"
```

should actually work (and it's simpler).

In case you have a program that has an unusual command line argument syntax where PowerShell's automatic quoting and parsing of arguments would interfere, you can use the stop-parsing token (`--%`):

```
PS Home:\> args --% (5 + 4) $foo (gci C:\)
argv[0] = H:\Batches\args.cmd
argv[1] = (5
argv[2] = +
argv[3] = 4)
argv[4] = $foo
argv[5] = (gci
argv[6] = C:\)
```

Mind you, those cases are rare, but oftentimes people try »fixing« such situations by heaping layer upon layer of parsing, often by using `Invoke-Expression` because they don't understand better. It's really not needed for invoking external commands.

Comment: This works on its own. But I want to capture the result in a variable after it has finished query. For this it has to wait after execution. with start-process is able to achieve this.

Comment: To capture the result in a variable, just assign this line to a variable, i.e. `$result = ...`. No need for `Start-Process` here either.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some `""` can you try the following and you do not need to escape the parenthesis :

```
   $output = "cmd /c ""C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\9.3\bin\psql.exe"" -t -d testdb1 -U myname -c ""SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'testdb2'"""
```

Comment: this returns nothing.